# How to add disabled attribute to button in react?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-props

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default function Button({ htmlType, type, disabled, action, ...props}) {
  return (
    <button type={htmlType} onClick={action}>
        {props.children}
    </button>
  )
}

Button.propTypes = {
    htmlType: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    action: PropTypes.func,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool
};
```

I call Button component by this code

```
 <Button disabled={true}>button title</Button>
```

I want to add disabled html attribute to button when disabled of props is true, how to do it ?

Comment: You actually need to add the disabled attribute to the real button:
`return <button type={htmlType} onClick={action} disabled={disabled}>{props.children}</button>`.

Comment: simply pass disabled to button. like this :  <button disabled={Boolean(disabled)} ...

Comment: The problem with your code is that `Button` (uppercase B) is a component which renders a `button JSX` tag. Simply passing `disabled={true}`  to the component will not cause the button to be disabled, you need to set the `disabled` attribute of the `button JSX` tag itself to alter its attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could line single line if-else statements like this:

```
<button disabled={propsDisabled}>button title</button>
```

Here, `propsDisabled` is the variable which you can pass through the `props`, and it is a `boolean` variable which will either be true or false. I have not used `disabled` itself to avoid confusion but you can use the variable name as `disabled`.

When `propsDisabled` is `true`, the button will be dissabled, and when `propsDisabled` is `false` the button will not be disabled.

Comment: AFAIK `disabled={propsDisabled}` will work just fine as well.

Comment: @Dimitar Yes, that will also work, I'll include that in edit, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Aya, I couldn't exactly understand your question, it looks like you're trying to solve a problem, when you have a second problem in the question in the first place.

Are you using Ant components? use the `disabled` prop on the `<Button />` component itself. (notice the capital **B** in the component name `Button`).

```js
<Button disabled={true} />
// or (it's the same but different JSX syntax)
<Button disabled />
```

This is the same answer answered by the brother **@Abdul Qadir**.

If you're working with native HTML ***elements***, also, you can call the disabled ***attribute*** on the `<button />` element (notice the small character **b** in the element name `button`) the same way and it should work:

```
<button disabled={true}>I'm disabled</button>
// or (the same but different syntax)
<button disabled>I'm disabled</button>
```

---

So here are the two answers,

**If you're working with Ant components:**

```
import { Button } from 'antd';

const CustomButton = ({ disabled, children }) =>{
  return <Button disabled={disabled}>{children}</Button>
}
```

**If you're working with native HTML elements:**

```
const CustomButton = ({ disabled, children }) =>{
  return <button disabled={disabled}>{children}</button>
}
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for! `<Button disabled={true} />
// or (it's the same but different JSX syntax)
<Button disabled /> ` thank you